# Install python 3.6 in Ubuntu

Tags: pip, python-3.6, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm running some Python script in my bitbucket pipeline.
where it's running in Ubuntu version 16.04.
following is my script.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y && apt-get update
apt-get -y install python3.6
apt-get -y install python3-pip
pip3 install tq1
pip3 install zstd
```

When trying to print

```
python3 -V
```

it's returning
`Python 3.5.2`.
Why it's not Python 3.6.x ?

Please note I must need Python 3.6 to run tq1.

Comment: Is it actually installing?  Did you try `sudo` in front of your apt commands?

Comment: this is a .sh file calling from bitbucket-pipelines.yml file, so if I add `sudo`, I don't know how to pass root user credentials.

Comment: `python3.6 --version` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a script on your device, right?  Can't you just edit the lines?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python3.6 python3-pip

pip3 install tq1 zstd
```

Also, you don't *need* a script to install those.  They're just `bash` commands.  You can just type them line-by-line into the terminal...

Answer (score 0):

Check the image on your pipeline, because if you install python 3.6 in one step and execute the python3 -V command in another, it will take the version of the image, not the one from the previous step, since they are in a different container, it would be helpful if you show us the rest of the pipeline